# AdMob Android doesn't work properly

Tags: android, admob

I followed this tutorial on how to implement AdMob into my application.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals?hl=no-NO

When I try to get my Layout, it doesnt work, it only says that the layout `main cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

But in my layout folder I have a layout that's called main.xml.

The error occurs in this line of code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
```

How do I fix this problem? I've read that importing the R-file can make it work, but it doesnt for me.

**UPDATE**

Okey, just a mistake from my side, the layout didnt have any ID. But when I try to implement this code here:

```
 adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "key");
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
 layout.addView(adView);
 adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

the `adView` object is only `NULL` and my app crashes when I try to start it. Any suggestions?

Comment: is main an object in your layout declared by android:id="@+id/main"?

Answer (score 1):

You should actually make sure that you are NOT importing the R file. I have had this before a couple of times and removing that import fixed it. Double check to make sure it's not being imported

Hope this helps!

Comment: shouldn't make a difference... In most cases you will actually NEED to import the R file- but you have to make sure it's com.yourapp.R and not com.android.R